# Error: "Dex file has invalid header" during Android Studio .apk build

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, dex

during my approach to build the latest version off my webview app I got an error:

```
Error: C:\Users\{user}\Documents\AndroidStudio\{appName}\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\104\de\mdlmlr\{appName}\R$string.dex, Dex file has invalid header
```

During the previous builds, this error never occurred but during the latest my pc once got stuck (whole OS) and I had to reboot it manually. Maybe this caused this error.
I couldn't find any help yet...
Thanks!

Comment: found a solution: android studio provides clean functionallity: Build > Clean Project

Comment: on my Samsung test device, everything is fine but while installing debug apk on Mi device it shows this error... Anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 5):

First
build->Clean project

Then
build->Rebuild project

[Click here to see the steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncI54.png)

that will work for most cases

but in case that didn't work
you have to update Gradle

I clicked "update" in the below pop up and that works for me

[update Gradle popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64zsP.png)